# Prolog function returns duplicate

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to learn prolog and I'm working on a problem where I have two functions:

```
findSiblings(X,L):-sibling(X,L). 
sibling(X,Y):-parent(Z,X),parent(Z,Y).
```

Where X and Y are names, and L is the return value. I would like for the `findSiblings` function to return the name's of X's siblings, and it does. However, the names get printed twice, because it matches both parents. I can't change the `sibling` function because it depends on a family tree where the only relationships are `parent(joe,bob)`. Any ideas on how I can solve this issue?

To clarify, say Daniel and Mark are brothers.

```
findSiblings(daniel,L).
```

returns

```
Mark;
Mark
```

Comment: You should provide a [mcve]. We should be able to run your code and see the results you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it could duplicate mark if mark has father and mother as parents.

Which would make duplicate calling such as

```
parent(john,daniel) -> parent(john,mark)
```

and then

```
parent(mary,daniel) -> parent(mary,mark)
```

Answer (score 1):

As for the given code, the following may help (note `X \= Y`):

```
parent(john, daniel).
parent(john, mark).

findSiblings(X,L) :- sibling(X,L). 
sibling(X,Y) :- parent(Z,X), parent(Z,Y).

findSiblings2(X,L) :- sibling2(X,L). 
sibling2(X,Y) :- parent(Z,X), parent(Z,Y), X \= Y.
```

(Try it in an online IDE: http://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/Siblings.pl.)